# Visual Studio Form Design

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, form-designer

I received an error page on my form design view and don't know what to do with it. I've included a .jpg of the error page. I went to the Help link on the page, but it only took me to the start page of Visual Studio. Does anyone know what to do in the case of an error like this?

I lost data when I got the error initially, and now methods used in the form design don't have a reference; for instance, the Load method no longer is valid on my code page. If anyone has an idea of what namespace I may be missing that will correct this, please let me know if that's the issue. Or if there is another solution, I'm open to your responses.[VS Form Design Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlVoG.jpg)

Comment: without seeing code it is difficult to determine what is wrong or missing. The error says the service being added already exists. Have you peeked into your ???.Designer.cs file to see if anything got corrupted? Or if there is a control that was accidentally duplicated?

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I think you're right about the corrupted file. I deleted one at a time my namespaces out of my reference list and then re-added them. Some of the errors that were listed were resolved. Unfortunately the System.Core namespace can't be deleted, so I couldn't re-add it. But it leaves me suspecting that it may have been corrupted. So I think I just need to start a fresh Project file, and copy over my code. What a pain...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a namespace solution to this problem, after deleting and re-adding namespaces in my reference list to rewrite any corrupted references. The System.Core  namespace could not be replaced. I created a new Project file and copied over my code into the new file. I had no problems with my code in the new file.